# Passing values from child declarative Jenkins pipeline to the parent

Tags: groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a declarative pipeline setup where the parent pipeline kicks off child pipeline via the "build job: workflow('workflow-name')" and i'm passing the parameters via the "parameters" directive

The question is, in the child pipeline in one of the stage i'm spawning a shell and writing few values to a file and via the readFile method the contents of the file is read and is set in a groovy variable defined at the top of the child pipeline.

This groovy variable (myVal) is visible in all the stages in the child pipeline, but I need to use the myVal in the parent pipeline,

Question 1 - Will the myVal be accessible in parent pipeline?
Question 2 - If it is not accessible then how can i access it, is it even viable?

As you can see, the child pipeline runs in a container but the parent pipeline will not, i.e. the agent on the parent pipeline is different at that of the child.

```
def myVal = ''
pipeline {
    agent {
     docker { 
        image 'myDockerImage'
        label 'myRemoteVM'
        args '-v /home/myuser:/home/myuser'
     }
    }
    stages {
       stage('step1') {
         steps {
            script {
              sh '''
                 ./myScript.sh
              '''
              myVal = readFile('myFileName.txt').trim()
            }
         }
       }
    }
 }
}
```